# Python program keeps crashing when writing to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, crash

I'm working on a Python program for school. The details are as specified:

> **Input**
>
> The first line of the input will be of the form n q, where n is
>   the number of pages in the encyclopedia, and q is the number of
>   questions to be answered. (1 <= n, q <= 10,000)
>
> Following this will be n lines, each describing a single page. The ith
>   of these lines will contain the single integer pi, the number of words
>   on page i. (0 <= pi <= 2,000,000,000)
>
> Following this will be q lines, each describing a single question.
>   Each of these lines will contain a single integer x, representing the
>   question, "How many words are there on page x?" (1 <= x <= n)
>
> **Output**
>
> For each question, your program should write a single line of
>   output. This line should contain a single integer, the number of words
>   on the requested page.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 6 5
> 1151
> 723
> 1321
> 815
> 780
> 931
> 4
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 1
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 815  
> 1321  
> 815  
> 780  
> 1151
> ```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
ency = open('encyin.txt').read().split()
n, q = int(ency[0])+2, int(ency[1])

with open('encyout.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in ency[n:n+q]:
        print(ency[2:n][int(i)-1], file=f)
```

I keep receiving an error message stating that my program has crashed when I submit it for checking. Could someone help me figure out what's causing this? Also sorry if the code is really sad to look at (I have no idea how to make things work properly haha). Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Does the error message give any details? Python usually doesn't just crash, it raises an error, including the failing line, that you use for debug.

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/NM7U3lV) is the error message I'm getting from the website. I've tried the options on the help page, to no avail. The program runs just fine in IDLE, just don't know what's setting the checker off.

Comment: ... not much feedback there. Does it show you output you print from your program? You could wrap it all an a try/except and print any errors. And put prints in the program itself.